# Power amp element's purpose

Tags: power, capacitor, amplifier, audio, diodes

From [100 watts OTL amplifier circuit using transistor MJ15003-MJ15004](https://www.eleccircuit.com/power-amplifier-otl-100w-by-transistor-mj15003mj15004-with-pcb/):
[image]

What is the purpose of C5 capacitor?

Why are there 3 diodes used? Not 4?

Comment: What is your reasoning for thinking that perhaps there should be four diodes?

Comment: Because I have 4 pn-junctions - 2 on top and 2 on bottom -to make 4*0,65 volt

Comment: Could it be that the designer of that circuit looked at the *maximum* (instantaneous) forward voltage drop of 1.1 V for that diode instead of the value at, say, 20 mA? Refs: [Vishay 1N400x](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf), [OnSemi 1N400x](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N4001-D.PDF)?

Comment: The question is rather, why 3 and not 2? Q4 and Q5 return current directly to common through R15 and R16.

Comment: In general you would need one diode for each of the Vbe drops of the 4 output transistors in this fully complementary design.  It does depend upon the actual transistors, diodes and desired quiescent current.  Normally an amplified diode would be used to allow quiescent current adjustment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not convinced the DC bias is stable or even centered at 45V out but C5 is definitely a Bootstrap Cap to shunt the AC current across R12 and thus raise it's equivalent input impedance.

Given the high open loop gain offered by Q3 , crossover distortion is less of an issue than the pop created during power on.

Comment: +1! I realized later that C5 was connected in that way, and any anti-thump (if any) would be only a secondary side effect.

Comment: But C2 and C3, what are they for? To push AC directly to ground without passing through R1 and R3?

Comment: In theory to regulate DC bias current without effects low frequency waves., in practice this circuit is a messy drifting DC feedback loop

Answer (score 7):

C5 is called a bootstrap capacitor as indicated by the other answers but they haven't described the main reason for needing it.

It is to increase the drive to the output transistors Q4 and Q6 and ensure the amplifier reaches its full output capability.

This is in addition to increasing the impedance at the collector of Q3 and increasing its gain as indicated by @Tony Stewart.

Without C5 the most positive that the base of Q4 can be driven is to the positive rail minus the voltage drop in R11 and R12 caused by Q4's base current.

At full output Q6 may need to pass about 5-6 Amps of current.  This will require 100mA or so of base current from Q4.  Q4 in turn will require 1-2 mA of base drive from R11 and R12.  Their combined value of 7.7k will drop 8-10V limiting the maximum positive excursion of the signal at Q6 emitter to about 80v. It will lose about 10volts of the possible output swing and corresponding output power.

With no signal the voltage across R12 will be abut 30V. With C5 in the circuit this voltage be maintained approximately constant even as the signal varies.

This current through R12 will be about 6mA and available to drive Q4 even if the base of Q4 is at the positive rail. The junction of R11 and R12 will swing up to about 120V (30v above the positive rail) during positive peaks of the signal. This can allow Q4 to go into saturation if required ensuring the maximum drive to Q6.

For the negative swing to Q5 and Q7 the same issue does not exist as Q3 can conduct as necessary to drive Q5 fully.

Many amplifier designs use a transistor arranged as a constant current source instead of R11, R12 and C5.  This results in a more symmetric drive to the output transistors and its proponents claim better lower distortion.

Comment: "The junction of R11 and R12 will swing up to about 120V (30v above the positive rail) during positive peaks of the signal."? I can't understand here. Why the junction of R11 and R12 is about 120V. I think that the output point is centered in the middle of power source - near 45V and the swing goes from that 45 v up and down! Where is 120V may be?

Comment: @MaxMil The output goes up and down by 45V from midpoint (45V). Since the capacitor C5 is charged (and keeps its voltage), when the output rises, the positive terminal of the capacitor rises too (it's because of the capacitor that actually the output can rise very close to the +90 rail). If the capacitor is charged at 30V, when the output is about 90V, the positive terminal of C5 will be 120V.

Comment: it may be semantics but the output doesn't add any drive to the base on its own, it is the shunting of R12 that reduces signal current into the base thus effectively raising the impedance so that R11 27k is the main load and not 5k R12.  With hfe1 * hfe2 * 8 > 80000, this is how bootstraps work so that Q3 becomes a common emitter high gain amp. But still easily distorted.

Comment: May you write the circuit path of C5 charge to clearly look the 120V total voltage? @next-hack